# How to add a div based on a mouse click after button click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made an HTML page that allows you to click a button to `add row and column` division. At the moment, the `row div` is added to the `container` div. I want to switch from the standard div adding to one that is mouse-click driven. This means that when a user `clicks` a button and selects a `div`, a row block is appended to that div. Looking for a solution

```js
var i = 0;
var j = 0;

let newColNode = null;

function addRow() {
  const row = document.createElement('div');
  row.className = 'bloc';
  row.id = "b" + ++i;

  document.getElementById('contentBox').append(row);

  row.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    console.log(newColNode)
    console.log(row)
    if (newColNode != null)
      row.appendChild(newColNode);
    newColNode = null
  });
}

// Column Addition

function addCol() {
  const col = document.createElement('div');
  col.className = 'bloc--inner';
  col.id = "c" + ++j;
  newColNode = col;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.main-content {
  float: left;
  width: calc(100%);
  height: 100%;
  background: #fafafa;
}

.header {
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.content-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 60px);
  padding: 15px;
}

button {
  background: #000;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.row-block {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px dashed #848484;
  padding: 20px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.row-block:hover {
  border-color: #2654d1;
}

.column-block {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
  flex-basis: 0;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 2px dashed #848484;
  background-color: #dedede;
  padding: 20px;
}

.column-block:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.column-block:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.row-block .each-draggable-item {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
  flex-basis: 0;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.gu-mirror {
  cursor: grabbing;
}

.container .ex-moved {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}

.container.ex-over {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

.handle {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  cursor: move;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.column-block h5 {
  margin: 0;
}


/* .gu-mirror {
    cursor: move;
    cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
    cursor: -moz-grabbing;
    cursor: grabbing;
    position: fixed !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    z-index: 9999 !important;
    opacity: 1;
}
.gu-hide {
    display: none !important;
}
.gu-unselectable {
    -webkit-user-select: none !important;
    -moz-user-select: none !important;
    -ms-user-select: none !important;
    user-select: none !important;
}
.gu-transit {
    opacity: 0.4;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=20)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=20);
} */

.gu-transit {
  opacity: 0.4;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=20)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=20);
  transition: .3s ease-out;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.bloc {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px dashed #848484;
  background: #ffefef;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.bloc--inner {
  margin: 0 10px;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
  flex-basis: 0;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 2px dashed #848484;
  background-color: #d4ecff;
  padding: 20px;
}

.bloc--inner:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.bloc--inner:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.bloc--inner .bloc {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main-content">
    <div class="header">
      <button class="add-row" onclick="addRow()">Add Row +</button>
      <button class="add-column" onclick="addCol()">Add Column +</button>
    </div>
    <div class="content-box" id="main-container">
      <div class="container" id="contentBox">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Currently the div is appedning to the container div

Comment: I don't know what you want exactly. What `add column` mean?

Comment: currently now there is a button called add column when we click on that a div is append to the container div

Comment: You said "This means that when a user clicks a button and selects a div, a row block is appended to that div. Looking for a solution". Where `add column` is needed?

Comment: i wanto change that appending, after button click user want to select a div  by a mouse click, the add row div must place on that div

Comment: You basically want a click event handler on your div rows that will add a CSS class like "active-div" to the one clicked and removes it from all other rows. Then just have the button append after the CSS class instead of at the end and you're good to go

Comment: you must use the event delegation principe, there lot of sample code about this on SO

Comment: So, you mean after `add row` button clicking, user click row => adding column to that row?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/unni2003pj/0dej8sah/1/

Comment: @Adrid add column is working correctly. i want the row appending based on mouse click over element

Comment: @icecub please help me

jsfiddle.net/unni2003pj/0dej8sah/1

Comment: I'm working on it. Just takes some time.

Comment: i will explian the senerio

1. click add row button -> select on blank area inside container (just eg.) -> then appen that div inisde container  2. assume that we added a row -> then click add row button -> select the below added row - > then the row must place inside row. if itis column then it will be inside column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this more or less the intended result? Click on a `div` and then click on either button to add the appropriate element to the previously clicked `div`?

```js
var i = 0;
var j = 0;

let parent=false;

/* delegated listener to set the global variable used to determine where new elements are added */
document.querySelector('#main-container > .container').addEventListener('click',e=>{
  parent=e.target;
});
/* remove elements using right-click */
document.querySelector('#main-container > .container').addEventListener('contextmenu',e=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  try{
    if( parent )parent.removeChild(e.target);
  }catch(err){
    console.clear();
    console.log(err.message);
  }
});





const warnuser=(e)=>{
  if( !parent ){
    return alert('Click a suitable parent to begin');
  }
  return true;
}

function addRow() {
  if( warnuser() ){
    i++;
    const row = document.createElement('div');
          row.className='bloc';
          row.id = `b${i}`;
    parent.append( row );
    return row;}
}
function addCol() {
  if( warnuser() ){
    j++;
    const col=document.createElement('div');
          col.className='bloc--inner';
          col.id = `c${j}`;
    parent.append( col );
    return col;
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/*
  to ensure user can see contentBox initially
*/
.container{
  border:2px dashed grey;
  padding:1rem
}
.bloc:after,
.bloc--inner:after{
  content:attr(id)
}



.wrapper {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.main-content {
  float: left;
  width: calc(100%);
  height: 100%;
  background: #fafafa;
}

.header {
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.content-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 60px);
  padding: 15px;
}

button {
  background: #000;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.row-block {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px dashed #848484;
  padding: 20px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.row-block:hover {
  border-color: #2654d1;
}

.column-block {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
  flex-basis: 0;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 2px dashed #848484;
  background-color: #dedede;
  padding: 20px;
}

.column-block:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.column-block:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.row-block .each-draggable-item {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
  flex-basis: 0;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.gu-mirror {
  cursor: grabbing;
}

.container .ex-moved {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}

.container.ex-over {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

.handle {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  cursor: move;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.column-block h5 {
  margin: 0;
}


/* .gu-mirror {
    cursor: move;
    cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
    cursor: -moz-grabbing;
    cursor: grabbing;
    position: fixed !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    z-index: 9999 !important;
    opacity: 1;
}
.gu-hide {
    display: none !important;
}
.gu-unselectable {
    -webkit-user-select: none !important;
    -moz-user-select: none !important;
    -ms-user-select: none !important;
    user-select: none !important;
}
.gu-transit {
    opacity: 0.4;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=20)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=20);
} */

.gu-transit {
  opacity: 0.4;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=20)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=20);
  transition: .3s ease-out;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.bloc {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px dashed #848484;
  background: #ffefef;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.bloc--inner {
  margin: 0 10px;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
  flex-basis: 0;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 2px dashed #848484;
  background-color: #d4ecff;
  padding: 20px;
}

.bloc--inner:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.bloc--inner:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.bloc--inner .bloc {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main-content">
  
    <div class="header">
      <button class="add-row" onclick="addRow()">Add Row +</button>
      <button class="add-column" onclick="addCol()">Add Column +</button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="content-box" id="main-container">
      <div class="container" id="contentBox"></div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Perhaps I have this backwards - having re-read the question.

---

If the process is to be initialised using the button to determine what is to be added  when the user clicks within the target area then perhaps this is better than the previous which does seem backwards to the perceived mode of operation.

```js
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
let bRow=false;
let bCol=false;

let parent=false;
let container=document.querySelector('#main-container > .container');
let header=document.querySelector('.header');


container.addEventListener('click',e=>{
  parent=e.target;
  if(bRow)addRow(e);
  if(bCol)addCol(e);
});

header.addEventListener('click',e=>{
  bRow=false;
  bCol=false;
  
  if( e.target.className=='add-row' )bRow=true;
  if( e.target.className=='add-column' )bCol=true;
});

container.addEventListener('contextmenu',e=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  try{
    if( parent )parent.removeChild( e.target );
  }catch(err){
    console.clear();
    console.log(err.message);
  }
});

function addRow(e) {
  i++;
  const row = document.createElement('div');
        row.className='bloc';
        row.id = `b${i}`;
  parent.append( row );
  bRow=false;
  return row;
}

function addCol(e) {
  j++;
  const col=document.createElement('div');
        col.className='bloc--inner';
        col.id = `c${j}`;
  parent.append( col );
  return col;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/*
  to ensure user can see contentBox initially
*/
.container{
  border:2px dashed fuchsia;
  background:silver;
  padding:1rem
}
.bloc:after,
.bloc--inner:after{
  content:attr(id)
}



.wrapper {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.main-content {
  float: left;
  width: calc(100%);
  height: 100%;
  background: #fafafa;
}

.header {
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.content-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 60px);
  padding: 15px;
}

button {
  background: #000;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.row-block {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px dashed #848484;
  padding: 20px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.row-block:hover {
  border-color: #2654d1;
}

.column-block {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
  flex-basis: 0;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 2px dashed #848484;
  background-color: #dedede;
  padding: 20px;
}

.column-block:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.column-block:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.row-block .each-draggable-item {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
  flex-basis: 0;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.gu-mirror {
  cursor: grabbing;
}

.container .ex-moved {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}

.container.ex-over {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

.handle {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  cursor: move;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.column-block h5 {
  margin: 0;
}


/* .gu-mirror {
    cursor: move;
    cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
    cursor: -moz-grabbing;
    cursor: grabbing;
    position: fixed !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    z-index: 9999 !important;
    opacity: 1;
}
.gu-hide {
    display: none !important;
}
.gu-unselectable {
    -webkit-user-select: none !important;
    -moz-user-select: none !important;
    -ms-user-select: none !important;
    user-select: none !important;
}
.gu-transit {
    opacity: 0.4;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=20)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=20);
} */

.gu-transit {
  opacity: 0.4;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=20)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=20);
  transition: .3s ease-out;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.bloc {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px dashed #848484;
  background: #ffefef;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.bloc--inner {
  margin: 0 10px;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
  flex-basis: 0;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 2px dashed #848484;
  background-color: #d4ecff;
  padding: 20px;
}

.bloc--inner:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.bloc--inner:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.bloc--inner .bloc {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main-content">
  
    <div class="header">
      <button class="add-row">Add Row +</button>
      <button class="add-column">Add Column +</button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="content-box" id="main-container">
      <div class="container" id="contentBox"></div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

---

To limit the number of rows that can be added to one can be achieved by setting `bRow=false` at the end of the `addRow` function. A further enhancement might be to ensure that columns can only be added within rows - probably using a `class` attribute when adding the column would be a suitable solution so that you check if the parent does not contain that class etc

---

Adjustable limitation for rows/cols and sanity checks to ensure that rows are not added within other rows and similar for cols.

```js
let bRow = false;
let bCol = false;

window.bLimitRows = true;
window.bLimitCols = false;

let parent = false;
let container = document.querySelector('#main-container > .container');
let checkboxes = document.querySelector('div.chkbx');
let header = document.querySelector('.header');


let togglebttns=(e)=>{
  resetbttns();
  e.target.classList.add('active');
  return true;
};
let resetbttns=()=>{
  header.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(bttn => bttn.classList.remove('active'));
};

container.addEventListener('click',e=>{
  parent = e.target;
  if( bRow ) addRow(e);
  if( bCol ) addCol(e);
});

header.addEventListener('click',e=>{
  bRow = false;
  bCol = false;
  if (e.target.className == 'add-row') bRow = true;
  if (e.target.className == 'add-column') bCol = true;
  return togglebttns(e);
});

checkboxes.addEventListener('click',e=>{
  window[e.target.name] = e.target.checked;
});

container.addEventListener('contextmenu',e=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  try {
    if (parent) parent.removeChild(e.target);
  } catch (err) {
    console.clear();
    console.log(err.message);
  }
});



function addRow(e) {
  if ( e.target.classList.contains('bloc') ) return;
  let row = document.createElement('div');
  row.className = 'bloc';
  row.dataset.label = 'R';
  parent.append(row);
  
  if (bLimitRows) {
    bRow = false;
    resetbttns();
  }
  return row;
}

function addCol(e) {
  if ( e.target.classList.contains('bloc--inner') || e.target == container ) return;
  let col = document.createElement('div');
  col.className = 'bloc--inner';
  col.dataset.label = 'C';
  parent.append(col);
  
  if (bLimitCols) {
    bCol = false;
    resetbttns();
  }
  return col;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*
 to ensure user can see contentBox initially
*/
.container {
  border: 2px dashed black;
  background: silver;
  padding: 1rem
}
.bloc:before {
  position: relative;
  content: attr(data-label)counter(row);
  top: calc(50% - 1rem);
  left: -2rem;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  background: yellow;
  border: 2px solid black;
  max-height: 1rem;
}

.bloc--inner:before {
  position: relative;
  content: attr(data-label)counter(col);
  top: -2rem;
  left: calc(50% - 2rem);
  padding: 0.25rem;
  background: lime;
  border: 2px solid black;
  max-height: 1rem;
}
.active {
  background: lime;
  color: black;
}





.wrapper {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  counter-reset: row;
  counter-reset: col;
}

.main-content {
  float: left;
  width: calc(100%);
  height: 100%;
  background: #fafafa;
}

.header {
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.content-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 60px);
  padding: 15px;
}

button {
  background: #000;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.row-block {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px dashed #848484;
  padding: 20px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.row-block:hover {
  border-color: #2654d1;
}

.column-block {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
  flex-basis: 0;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 2px dashed #848484;
  background-color: #dedede;
  padding: 20px;
}

.column-block:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.column-block:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.row-block .each-draggable-item {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
  flex-basis: 0;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.gu-mirror {
  cursor: grabbing;
}

.container .ex-moved {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}

.container.ex-over {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

.handle {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  cursor: move;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.column-block h5 {
  margin: 0;
}

.gu-transit {
  opacity: 0.4;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=20)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=20);
  transition: .3s ease-out;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.bloc {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px dashed #848484;
  background: #ffefef;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  counter-increment: row;
}

.bloc--inner {
  margin: 0 10px;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
  flex-basis: 0;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 2px dashed #848484;
  background-color: #d4ecff;
  padding: 20px;
  counter-increment: col;
}

.bloc--inner:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.bloc--inner:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.bloc--inner .bloc {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='main-content'>
    <div class='chkbx'>
      <label>Limit Rows<input type='checkbox' name='bLimitRows' value=1 checked></label>
      <label>Limit Cols<input type='checkbox' name='bLimitCols' value=1></label>
    </div>
    <div class='header'>
      <button class='add-row'>Add Row +</button>
      <button class='add-column'>Add Column +</button>
    </div>
    <div class='content-box' id='main-container'>
      <div class='container' id='contentBox'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hum... I would have rather seen this with a different border color for the active row / element...

Comment: i will explain the actual process:

1. there are 2 buttons one is add row and other is add column.
2. currnt code when clicking add column a pink div block is append to container
3. after Add column button clicking and select any added pink row block , a blue colur box will append inside

this is the actual process. 

requiremnt: I want the row block (pink box) to only be appended when any element is clicked with the mouse. and the add column remain same as oer current code

Comment: But, at first there isn't any pink box.

Comment: yea, want to be added by add column button. currently its happening.  

requirement: intiallly content box is blank  then click add button -> mouse click on any div -> then the row must added on  that selected div (element click)

Comment: Thanks for the solutiion. i need one more suggestion , how to restrict row divto 1 per click, now its adding continously on each click.

Comment: Thanks mate. Thankyou for your valueable time. Cheers !!<3

Answer (score 1):

Basically to get what you want, I added some states to the buttons that will enable / disable their functionality and just allow you to click where you want to add a row or col.

```js
var i = 0;
var j = 0;

let addRowBool = false;
let addColBool = false;

function addRowState(){
    if(addColBool){
    addColBool = !addColBool;
  }
    addRowBool = !addRowBool;
  
  setColors();
}

function addColState(){
    if(addRowBool){
    addRowBool = !addRowBool;
  }
    addColBool = !addColBool;
  setColors();
}

function setColors(){
    if(addRowBool) {
    document.querySelector(".add-row").style.backgroundColor = "green";
  } else {
    document.querySelector(".add-row").style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
  
  if(addColBool) {
    document.querySelector(".add-column").style.backgroundColor = "green";
  } else {
    document.querySelector(".add-column").style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
}

function addRowOrCol(evt){
    if(addRowBool){
    i++;
    const row = document.createElement('div');
    const txt = document.createTextNode("row"+i);
    row.appendChild(txt);
    row.className = 'bloc';
    row.id = "b" + i;
    
    evt.target.appendChild(row);
  }
  else if(addColBool){
    
    const col = document.createElement('div');
    const txt = document.createTextNode("col"+j);
    col.appendChild(txt);
    col.className = 'bloc--inner';
    col.id = "c" + ++j;

    evt.target.appendChild(col);
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.add-row {
  background-color: red;
}

.add-column {
  background-color: red;
}

.wrapper {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.main-content {
  float: left;
  width: calc(100%);
  height: 100%;
  background: #fafafa;
}

.header {
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.content-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 60px);
  padding: 15px;
}

button {
  background: #000;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.row-block {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px dashed #848484;
  padding: 20px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.row-block:hover {
  border-color: #2654d1;
}

.column-block {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
  flex-basis: 0;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 2px dashed #848484;
  background-color: #dedede;
  padding: 20px;
}

.column-block:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.column-block:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.row-block .each-draggable-item {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
  flex-basis: 0;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.gu-mirror {
  cursor: grabbing;
}

.container {
  min-height: 50px;
  min-width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

.container .ex-moved {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}

.container.ex-over {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

.handle {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  cursor: move;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.column-block h5 {
  margin: 0;
}


/* .gu-mirror {
    cursor: move;
    cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
    cursor: -moz-grabbing;
    cursor: grabbing;
    position: fixed !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    z-index: 9999 !important;
    opacity: 1;
}
.gu-hide {
    display: none !important;
}
.gu-unselectable {
    -webkit-user-select: none !important;
    -moz-user-select: none !important;
    -ms-user-select: none !important;
    user-select: none !important;
}
.gu-transit {
    opacity: 0.4;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=20)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=20);
} */

.gu-transit {
  opacity: 0.4;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=20)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=20);
  transition: .3s ease-out;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.bloc {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px dashed #848484;
  background: #ffefef;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.bloc--inner {
  margin: 0 10px;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
  flex-basis: 0;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 2px dashed #848484;
  background-color: #d4ecff;
  padding: 20px;
}

.bloc--inner:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.bloc--inner:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.bloc--inner .bloc {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main-content">
    <div class="header">
      <button class="add-row" onclick="addRowState()">Add Row +</button>
      <button class="add-column" onclick="addColState()">Add Column +</button>
    </div>
    <div class="content-box" id="main-container">
      <div class="container" id="contentBox" onclick="addRowOrCol(event)">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Partially correct. this code allow me to add multiple rows inside a singlerow athe same time, we want to limit it by 1 per add column click and can place the row div outside another  row diiv.  column can only add inside row and a column can hold row too

Comment: @unnikrishnanpj I suggest you attempt to add that yourself. I've answered your question, you can't expect me to continue developing the script with follow up questions. Keep in mind that Stack Overflow is here to help you fix problems that you've encountered. Not to do your job for you. Everything you need is practically already there. All you need to do is add more booleans to keep track of added rows / columns and disable functionality if true.

Comment: sorry bro, i dont mean that. please suggest a way to place the add row outside the another row. Now  it placing inside onnly for the first time

Comment: @unnikrishnanpj Just increase the initial size of the container div. I made it only 50 pixels high so you have a starting point. But you can make it larger and it'll allow you to add more than one row.

Comment: Thankyou for your valuable time. Cheers !!